# C++ error when trying to create a vector of tokens

Tags: c++, class, vector, constructor, token

I'm currently working in Stroustrup's "Principles and practices" book for learning how to program using C++. I'm at a part where they introduce Tokens and show how to use them. I was attempting to do a simple test to make sure I'm constructing the class correctly and using the tokens and vector correctly.

Below is an example of what I've done.

```
class Test{
public:
    char kind;
    double value;
    Test(char ch)
        :kind(ch), value(0){}
    Test(char ch, double val)
        :kind(ch),value(val){}

};

int main(){

    vector<Test>testLoop;

    for(char i = 'a'; i < 'k'; i++){
        testLoop.push_back(i, 1);
    }
    cout << testLoop[5].kind << endl << testLoop[5].value;
}
```

What I'm trying to accomplish (I think) is having a vector of objects that both obtain the members of the class 'Test', do a loop that adds a few of them to the vector 'testLoop', (and puts 1 in all the value members) then prints out the value of testLoop[5].kind and testLoop[5].value.

The specific errors I'm getting are:

```
|25|error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<Test>::push_back(char&, int)'|
candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
```

Any and all criticism and help is welcome! - Thankyou

Answer (score 4):

[`std::vector::push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) takes an object of the type being stored in the vector. So in this case you would need

```
testLoop.push_back(Test(i, 1));
```

You can also use [`std::vector::emplace_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back), which takes the type's constructor arguments and constructs an object in the vector directly:

```
testLoop.emplace_back(i, 1);
```

Comment: Or alternatively, `testLoop.push_back({i, 1});`.

Comment: Thankyou so much! It did what I wanted it to do, but I don't fully understand why this works. With the push_back(Test(i, 1));, am I calling on the constructor? or the class?

Comment: @Claystor `Test(i, 1)` calls one of the `Test` constructors and produces a `Test` object. That is copied into the vector.

Answer (score 1):

Class Test has two constructors.
The constrcutor with one parameter

```
Test(char ch)
    :kind(ch), value(0){}
```

is called a conversion constructor because it in fact convert an object of type (in this case) `char` to an object of type `Test`

So you might call method  `push_back` the following way

```
for(char i = 'a'; i < 'k'; i++){
    testLoop.push_back( i );
}
```

In this case the compiler would use the conversion constructor because you did not write explicitly

```
for(char i = 'a'; i < 'k'; i++){
    testLoop.push_back( Test( i ) );
}
```

so the compiler will do this implicitly.

However if you would declare the constructor with the function specifier `explicit`

```
explicit Test(char ch)
    :kind(ch), value(0){}
```

then the compiler could not call it implicitly and would issue an error. In this case you have to specify the constructtor explicitly by yourself

```
for(char i = 'a'; i < 'k'; i++){
    testLoop.push_back( Test( i ) );
}
```

If you use two arguments as in your loop

```
for(char i = 'a'; i < 'k'; i++){
    testLoop.push_back(i, 1);
}
```

the compiler is not so smart and can not implicitly call the constructor that has two parameters. It is simpler for it to issue an error.

However you could use an initializer list provided that the compiler supports this feature of C++ 2011

```
for(char i = 'a'; i < 'k'; i++){
    testLoop.push_back( { i, 1 } );
}
```

In this case the compiler could call implicitly the constructor with two parameters.